# Using .net mongo driver get property from document with filter

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a document in mongo that from the top looks like

```
public sealed record ScopeData(
    ObjectId Id,
    Guid ScopeData,
    ReadOnlyCollection<Data> Data);
```

And Data looks like

```
public sealed record Data(Guid DataIdentifier, IReadOnlyCollection<Details> Details);
```

And details:

```
public sealed record SampleData(DateTime TimeStamp, double Value);
```

looks simpel enagh, but now I want to get only SampleData but for certain ScopeData ScopeId and certain Data with DataIdentifier. So I tried something like

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<SampleData> GetSampleDataAsync(Guid scopeId, Guid dataIdentifier)
{
    var scopeIdBinData = new BsonBinaryData(scopeId, GuidRepresentation.Standard);
    var dataIdentifierBinData = new BsonBinaryData(dataIdentifier, GuidRepresentation.Standard);

    var matchScopeId = new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument("ScopeId", scopeIdBinData));
    var unwindData = new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$Data.SampleData");
    var matchDataIdentifier = new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument("Data.DataIdentifier", dataIdentifierBinData));
    var sampleData = new BsonDocument("$project", new BsonDocument
    {
        { "TimeStamp", "$Data.SampleData.TimeStamp" },
        { "Value", "$Data.SampleData.Value" },
    });

    BsonDocument[] pipeline = { matchScopeId, unwindData, matchDataIdentifier, sampleData };
    using IAsyncCursor<SampleData> cursor = await _collection.AggregateAsync<SampleData>(pipeline);
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        foreach (SampleData sampleData in cursor.Current)
        {
            yield return sampleData;
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives no result, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you use LINQ and `AsQuerable` method?

Comment: in general, if some complex query doesn't work as you expect, the guide is to simplify the query as more as possible by removing stages until you will limit query only to problematic one. For example is anything returned when you use only `$match`?